# WebMatrix PHP Query Not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, webmatrix

Just a heads up I have been writing PHP now for about 3 days. I am having trouble with a query. When I run the query in the query tool it finds exactly what I am looking for. I have tried every variation of syntax I can think of from using LIKE (how it is right now) and = and i cannot get it to work. I am sure there is a simpler way to do the rest of the code but my main concern right now is the query. Thanks for all the help.

```
        $Incident_D = $_POST['Incident_D'];
        $Incident_D = strtotime($Incident_D);
        $Incident_T = $_POST['Incident_T'];
        $Incident_T = strtotime($Incident_T);
        $Incident_T = ($Incident_T % 86400);
        $Incident_DT = $Incident_D + $Incident_T; 
        $sql = "SELECT dept.Department From department dept inner join near_miss NM on dept.Dept_Index = NM.Dept_Index Where NM.Incident_DT LIKE '%" . $Incident_DT . "%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $result1 = $row['Department'];
            }
            } else {
                $result1 = "No Response";
            }

       $result = $result1;
```

If i manually type in the value for $Incident_DT it is able to find it. This is why I think the problem is in how the value is being stored in $Incident_DT. also when I echo the value for the variable and paste it into the query tool it works.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: What datatype is your `Incident_DT` column? you should always use date/time types for this data see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: Incident_DT is an integer

Comment: Where is your error checking?

Comment: I tried to use die on the mysqli_query but it did not generate an error. It just acts like it cannot find any rows that match the query. I end up getting the No Response. I can show the entire code for this section if it will help but it is quite long.

Comment: So I think I figured out the problem. But, I have no clue how to fix it. This page posts data to a database and then queries the data back out into the form during the same POST. The problem I seem to be running into is that because they happen concurrently the data does not exist at the time it is queried. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT dept.Department From `department` dept inner join near_miss NM on dept.Dept_Index = NM.Dept_Index Where NM.Incident_DT LIKE '%" . $Incident_DT . "%'";
```

The back tick is necessary for PHP on the TABLENAME.

Comment: That did not work. In another section i use:             "SELECT dept.Department From department dept inner join near_miss NM on dept.dept_index = NM.Dept_index Where NM.NM_Index = " . $Rpt_Num; and it works really well.

Comment: It's not *necessary*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

declare a new variable with value:

```
$filter_var="%".$Incident_DT."%";
```

Then:

```
       $sql = "SELECT dept.Department From department dept inner join near_miss NM 
on dept.Dept_Index = NM.Dept_Index Where NM.Incident_DT LIKE '$filter_var'";
```

Comment: I am sure this is a silly question but what do they % do in this situation?